# count distinct elements in every window of size k

Tags: java, arrays

This is the function i have written for count distinct elements in every window of size  k. But i am getting wrong answer for input

n=17 , k=2

69 68 30 83 31 63 24 68 36 30 3 23 59 70 68 94 57

I am getting output 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 1 1 2

correct output is 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2

How can 1 came in output if in given  window of size (k= 2) , there are no similar elements?

```
void countDistinct(int arr[], int k, int n)
{
int i,j,l,m=0;
 l=0;
while(m!=n){
    int count=0;
    m=k+l;
    for( i=l;i<m;i++){
       for( j=0;j<i;j++){
        if(arr[i]==arr[j]){
            break;
        }   
       }
      if(i==j){
          count++;
      }
   }
   l++;
   System.out.print(count+" "); 
}
```

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a free debugging service, and you should show your attempts at debugging the code with a debugger or other simpler methods such as debug print statements. You can also test each part of the code separately to figure out exactly which part of the code is causing the problem, and make a [mcve]. This won't be the only time you end up with a bug in your code, and learning to debug your programs will help you much more than having someone find the bug for you. http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/ Lastly, you haven't even stated what language this is in.

Comment: Try adding some `System.out.println` statements within the inner loops, and dump the state of your variables. It will be easier to follow what the program is doing

Comment: "_count distinct elements in every window of size k_" which means ? You want to know how many different value you have in an array ?

Comment: Like [Count different values in array in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32444193/4391450) or [Count the number of unique elements in a sorted array](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/114073/105835) or a lot of other post on StackExchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the equal elements in array, when `m=8` and `l=6`=>`i=l`:
in first loop,  `i=6`, condition is `i<m`, then the execution of next for loop starts and in the second for loop, till `j=5<6` condition, there are no equal elements so codes continue with

```
      if(i==j){ //i =6, j =6
          count++;
      }
```

in the next execution of code, `count` will be 1. After  `if(i==j)` condition, 2nd loop is over and then get back to first loop with the condition `i=7<8` (because of the increment `i++`).
in case of `i=7` and `i=7<8`, code starts the execution of next for loop again, and in the second for loop, till `j=6<7` condition, there are equal elements inside array: `arr[7]` and `arr[1]` are equal *68* so you will go to the following if statement and then loop will break and prints count as 1:

```
      if (arr[7] == arr[1]) {
         break;
      }
```

Debug your codes on the IDE. You will see the result.

Comment: Thank you . I got my answer

Comment: You can read more about [arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) and [for-loop statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)